# libgdx sprite or animation not rotating like a homing (array issues)

Tags: arrays, animation, arraylist, libgdx

well i am a noob at java and libgdx. i got the homing bullet working with the help of someone. now i am smashing my head as to how i can make it rotate so it faces the ball (which is the main character) when it goes around it or when it is coming towards it. the bullet is facing <--- and the code below is what i have done so far. also i used sprites for the bullet and also animation method.

Also how do i make it an array/arraylist which is best so i can have multiple bullets at random or placed places. i tried many things nothing workd :(

thank you for the help.

// below is the bullet or enemy if you want to call it.

```
public class Bullet extends Sprite {

public static final float BULLET_HOMING = 6000; 
public static final float BULLET_SPEED = 300; 
private Vector2 velocity;
private float lifetime;


public Bullet(float x, float y) {
 velocity = new Vector2(0, 0);
 setPosition(x, y);
}

public void update(float delta) {
 float targetX = GameWorld.getBall().getX();
 float targetY = GameWorld.getBall().getY();
 float dx = targetX - getX();
 float dy = targetY - getY();

 float distToTarget = (float) Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); 
 dx /= distToTarget;
 dy /= distToTarget;
 dx *= BULLET_HOMING;
 dy *= BULLET_HOMING;
 velocity.x += dx * delta;
 velocity.y += dy * delta;

 float vMag = (float) Math.sqrt(velocity.x * velocity.x + velocity.y * velocity.y);
 velocity.x /= vMag;
 velocity.y /= vMag;
 velocity.x *= BULLET_SPEED;
 velocity.y *= BULLET_SPEED;

 Vector2 v = velocity.cpy().scl(delta);
 setPosition(getX() + v.x, getY() + v.y);
 setOriginCenter(); 
 setRotation(velocity.angle());
 lifetime += delta;
 setRegion(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(lifetime));
 }
}
```

// this is where i load the images.

```
public class AssetLoader {
public static Animation bulletAnimation;
public static Sprite bullet1, bullet2;

public static void load() {

texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("SpriteN1.png"));
texture.setFilter(TextureFilter.Nearest, TextureFilter.Nearest);

bullet1 = new Sprite(texture, 380, 350, 45, 20);
bullet1.flip(false, true);

bullet2 = new Sprite(texture, 425, 350, 45, 20);
bullet2.flip(false, true);

Sprite[] bullets = { bullet1, bullet2 };
bulletAnimation = new Animation(0.06f, aims);
bulletAnimation.setPlayMode(Animation.PlayMode.LOOP);
}

public static void dispose() {
// We must dispose of the texture when we are finished.
texture.dispose();
}
```

// this is for the rendering of the images etc

```
public class GameRenderer {
private Bullet bullet;
private Ball ball;

public GameRenderer(GameWorld world) {
myWorld = world;
cam = new OrthographicCamera();
cam.setToOrtho(true, 480, 320);

batcher = new SpriteBatch();
// Attach batcher to camera
batcher.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(cam.combined);

// Call helper methods to initialize instance variables
initGameObjects();
initAssets();
}

private void initGameObjects() {
ball = GameWorld.getBall();
bullet = myWorld.getBullet();
scroller = myWorld.getScroller();
}

private void initAssets() {
ballAnimation = AssetLoader.ballAnimation;
bulletAnimation = AssetLoader.bulletAnimation;
}

public void render(float runTime) {

Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL30.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

batcher.begin();
// Disable transparency 
// This is good for performance when drawing images that do not require
// transparency.
batcher.disableBlending();

// The ball needs transparency, so we enable that again.
batcher.enableBlending();


batcher.draw(AssetLoader.ballAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), ball.getX(), ball.getY(), ball.getWidth(), ball.getHeight());

batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime), bullet.getX(), bullet.getY());

// End SpriteBatch
batcher.end();
}
}
```

// this is to load the image etc on the screen i guess

```
public class GameWorld {

public static Ball ball;
private Bullet bullet;
private ScrollHandler scroller;

public GameWorld() {
ball = new Ball(480, 273, 32, 32);
bullet = new Bullet(10, 10);
scroller = new ScrollHandler(0);
}

public void update(float delta) {
ball.update(delta);
bullet.update(delta);
scroller.update(delta);
}

public static Ball getBall() {
return ball;
}

public ScrollHandler getScroller() {
return scroller;
}

public Bullet getBullet() { 
return bullet;
}
}
```

so there is the whole thing. the images are loaded via the AssetLoader then to the GameRenderer and GameWorld via the Bullet class. i am guessing that is how it is. sorry newbie so still learning.

thank you in advace for the help or any advice.

ps i posted this on gamedev and if it a double post please let me know and i will take it down.
please don't penelize me as i am a newbie 
thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the animation to just sprites and iterate through an array try that out and see if that works.
also 
do bullet.draw(batcher); instead.
Try that
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to **provide a rotation to the bullet** too. Here is the [**API of `MathUtils`**.](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/math/MathUtils.html)

```
Vector2 vel = bullet.getVelocity();
float xComponent = vel.x;
float yComponent = vel.y;
float rotation = MathUtils.atan2(yComponent, xComponent)
                     * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;
```

Create `getVelocity()` method in `Bullet` class too.

---

**Apply that rotation to the bullet**'s sprite. Here is the [**API of `SpriteBatch` `draw()` method**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/SpriteBatch.html#draw%28com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29)

Replace

```
batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime),
                 bullet.getX(), bullet.getY());
```

with

```
batcher.draw(AssetLoader.bulletAnimation.getKeyFrame(runTime),
                 bullet.getX(), bullet.getY(), bullet.getWidth(), bullet.getHeight(),
                 1.0f, 1.0f, rotation);
```

---

Regarding your second question about **multiple bullets**, I'd suggest you use [**`Array` class provided by LibGDX**](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html).
It is easy to use and fast too.

Hope this helps.
Good luck.

Comment: Animation would not be a problem. Animation just changes the texture and is decoupled from drawing logic. There can be any reasoning about the exception only if you show stack-trace.

Comment: Example of Arrays is available at https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/SimpleApp . Check out how rain drops are used in that source.

Comment: Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.aozora.GameObjects.Bullet.update(Bullet.java:36)
 at com.aozora.GameWorld.GameWorld.update(GameWorld.java:30)
 at com.aozora.Screen.GameScreen.render(GameScreen.java:32)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.render(Game.java:46)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:206)
 at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)

Comment: the line is this                                                                   float rotation = MathUtils.atan2(bullet.getVelocity().y, bullet.getVelocity().x)
                     * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees;

Comment: Write `bullet.getVelocity();` before that line. If the exception shifts to that line, your getVelocity method is returning null. You can easily fix it. There was also other irrelavant typo in my code of draw. please copy it again.

Comment: its doing the same. and in the Vector2 getVelocity i am returning return velocity. try running my entire code and see what happens you will see the same error. wish i could email you directly or something. this issue has been going on for too long please help. Thank you

Comment: Well I guess the velocity being returned is null. Try writing `bullet.getVelocity().x;` before that line.

Comment: cannot add .x after bullet.getVelocity(), won't let me do this bullet.getVelocity().x; as an error comes up saying -Syntax error, insert "AssignmentOperator Expression" to complete Expression- can you run the code and see what result you get maybe that might help. Thanks

Comment: Check the edit please. This should boil down your error. Good luck.